# Search functionality is not working for the frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]I am getting data from the backend using postman. But when i am using frontend for the same, it is not working. I am getting errors like 
1.TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
2.Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of null.

I think, I am getting this error because cards are not able to render when I am searching.The backend data is coming as a array.

[image]

```
const styles = theme => ({
  appBar: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
  layout: {
    width: 'auto',
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(1100 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
      width: 1100,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
    },
  },
  cardGrid: {
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 8}px 0`,
  },
  card: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

class Products extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: [],
      searchString: ''
    };
    this.onSearchInputChange = this.onSearchInputChange.bind(this);
    this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProducts();
  }



  // delete = id => {
  //   axios.post('http://localhost:9022/products/delete/' + id)
  //     .then(res => {
  //       let updatedProducts = [...this.state.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);
  //       this.setState({ products: updatedProducts });
  //     });
  // }

  delete = id => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:9022/products/delete/' + id)
      .then(res => {

        this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
          let updatedProducts = [...prevState.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);
          return ({
            products: updatedProducts
          });
        });
      });
  }

  getProducts() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getAll')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ products: res.data }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.products);
        });
      });
  }

  onSearchInputChange = (event) => {
    let newSearchString = '';
    if (event.target.value) {
      newSearchString = event.target.value;
    }
    axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getproducts' + newSearchString)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ products: res.data });
        console.log(this.state.products);
      });
    this.getProducts();
  }

  // onSearchInputChange(event) {
  //   let newSearchString = '';
  //   if (event.target.value) {
  //     newSearchString = event.target.value;
  //   }

  //   // call getProducts once React has finished updating the state using the callback (second argument)
  //   this.setState({ searchString: newSearchString }, () => {
  //     this.getProducts();
  //   });
  // }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TextField style={{ padding: 24 }}
          id="searchInput"
          placeholder="Search for products"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={this.onSearchInputChange} />
        <CssBaseline />
        <main>
          <div className={classNames(classes.layout, classes.cardGrid)}>
            <Grid container spacing={40}>
              {this.state.products.map(currentProduct => (
                <Grid item key={currentProduct.id} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                  <Card className={classes.card}>

                    <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                        {currentProduct.title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        {currentProduct.price}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>

                      <Button size="small" color="primary" component={Link} to={"/products/" + currentProduct.id}>
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                      <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => this.delete(currentProduct.id)}>
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                    </CardActions>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

Products.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Products);
```

Comment: Please add a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For starters, that's `getproducts' + newSearchString`, while you expect a query to be delimited with `/`. Check what your request and response are in network tab and proceed from there.

Comment: got it. minor error.But After search,When I delete the search string,it is giving the same error.

Comment: @Suman It's specific to how the backend responds to particular requests. You're the only person who can debug them. That you get this error means that backend responds with something else rather than an array.

Comment: Could be that in some situation `this.state.products` is setted to `null`? Try adding a validation before calling `map()`-> `{this.state.products && this.state.products.map(…`

Answer (score 2):

It has been observed that, you have added wrong URL of `getproducts`, slash is missing in the URL. Please find details below:

If search-string is r, then you are using this URL of getproducts: `http://localhost:9022/products/getproductsr`

which is wrong and it should be `http://localhost:9022/products/getproducts/r`

Hence you have to change your code of retrieving products as follows:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getproducts/' + newSearchString)
.then(res => {
    this.setState({ products: res.data });
    console.log(this.state.products);
});
```

Also it will be good to provide a check for undefined/null for this.state.products and then render the components because it is possible that products might be null if one provide wrong URL and undefined as axios request is async. Hence by adding 'this.state.products && ' in existing render code will be good to avoid such issues. I have updated your render function, please find it below:

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TextField style={{ padding: 24 }}
          id="searchInput"
          placeholder="Search for products"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={this.onSearchInputChange} />
        <CssBaseline />
        <main>
          <div className={classNames(classes.layout, classes.cardGrid)}>
            <Grid container spacing={40}>
              {this.state.products && this.state.products.map(currentProduct => (
                <Grid item key={currentProduct.id} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                  <Card className={classes.card}>

                    <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                        {currentProduct.title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        {currentProduct.price}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>

                      <Button size="small" color="primary" component={Link} to={"/products/" + currentProduct.id}>
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                      <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => this.delete(currentProduct.id)}>
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                    </CardActions>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Hope it will help..

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one:

**You just missed the slash in the api end Point** as below : Use this

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getproducts/' + newSearchString)
```

instead of :

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getproducts' + newSearchString)
```